# Запрет повторного голосования

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2

Здравствуйте. Сделал голосовалку и появилась необходимость запретить повторное голосование. Решил через id пользователя. Для этого создал таблицу и в ней два поля user_id и poll_id. То есть при заходе в голосование ищем в таблице все id текущего голосования, берем id текущего пользователя и если есть совпадения - в данном голосовании уже был этот пользователь, то запрещаем ему голосовать здесь, если id пользователя не совпадает ни с одним id голосования, то даем ему проголосовать и записываем в таблицу id голосования и id пользователя.
Скажите пожалуйста я правильно мыслю ? Или нагородил фигни ?
И эта таблица ведь должна быть связана с таблицами user и poll ?

Comment: Правильный подход. Только не надо искать всех проголосовавших по данному опросу и потом сравнивать с id юзера. Сразу ищете наличие строки таблицы с id юзера и id голосования. Если такой строки нет, то даете голосовать.

Comment: Направление правильное, чуть-чуть можно подкорректировать в мелочах. Берите `COUNT` записей по текущему пользователю и голосованию, сами записи вам не нужны. Если ноль записей - можно голосовать, если не ноль -- нельзя. Выше вам практически  том же самом писали, поддерживаю. Я лишь добавляю, что вам достаточно `COUNT` использовать: меньше данных передавать от SQL, меньше оперативки расходовать.

Comment: `COUNT` как раз ни сколько не лучше, а вот `LIMIT 1` лучше :)

Comment: Вы не учитываете, что после того как одной выборкой вы не найдете пользователя, и до того как вставите его, проходит время, за которое он там вполне может появиться.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian как он там появится, если запись произойдет только после голосования ?

Comment: @AlexeyDunin с параллельного запроса, открываешь два браузера, голосуешь одновременно. Поэтому адекватный способ - поставить ограничение на уникальность поля в бд, и писать без проверки, если не удалось - значит был пользователь уже, удалось - не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде получилось, вот код контроллера:

```
public function actionPoll($id, $user_id, $poll_id)
{
    $single = Poll::getOne($id);
    $getdata = PollUser::getData($user_id, $poll_id);

    $u = Yii::$app->user->id;

    if ($u != $getdata->user_id && $id != $getdata->poll_id) {


        if ($single->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


            if ($single->count1) {
                $single->updateCounters(['count1' => 1]);
            }
            if ($single->count2) {
                $single->updateCounters(['count2' => 1]);
            }
            if ($single->count3) {
                $single->updateCounters(['count3' => 1]);
            }

            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO poll_user (user_id, poll_id) VALUES ($u, $id)")->execute();


            return $this->redirect("/site/poll/?id=$single->id&user_id=$u&poll_id=$single->id");
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('pollonlyresult', ['single' => $single, 'getdata' => $getdata]);
    }
    return $this->render('poll', ['single' => $single, 'getdata' => $getdata]);
}
```

Берем голосование. Берем данные из проверочной таблицы. Получаем id залогиненого юзера - проверяем на совпадения в проверочной таблице - если нет совпадений, то голосуем и записываем текущего юзера и голосование в таблицу. Редиректим на страницу с результатами. Если же есть совпадения, то сразу редиректим на страницу с результатами. Вроде бы так, большое спасибо всем кто ответил.

Answer (score 3):

Ваше решение правильное и адекватное. Добавьте уникальный составной ключ на таблицу (user_id, poll_id), тогда база данных и сама не допустит одинаковых записей в БД и следовательно нескольких голосов одного пользователя по одному голосованию. Внешние ключи также желательно добавить на таблицы user и poll.

Перед голосованием делайте запрос на данную таблицу по уникальному составному ключу и при наличии записи делайте запрет голосования, также данную выбранную запись можно записывать в кеш, чтобы лишний раз не обращаться к таблице.

Возможно, но не обязательно, для дополнительной информации добавить туда дату и время, когда пользователь проголосовал, здесь будет видна статистика голосований, а в будущем Вы сможете добавить различный функционал, связанный с ограничением голосования по времени или количеству голосов за определенный интервал.

Comment: А можно добавить еще и как человек голосовал, чтобы проголосовавший, например, мог отменить свое голосование / переголосовать.